# WebRequest Checking If File Exisits on Remote Server Always Returning True Due to 404 Redirect

Tags: c#, validation, http-status-code-404, webrequest

I have a fileshare remote server for all my files. I want to check if they exist before displaying them.

This works great, but breaks when the file does not exist as on the web site i have an auto 404 redirect in place, thus if the file doesn't exist, it always returns as status code 200 or TRUE as the webpage in its mind does exist since it redirects and it present.

How can i get around this?

```
public bool verifyFile(string filePath)
    {
        bool result = true;
        string Domain = "http://www.SiteName.com/";

        try
        {
            WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(Domain + filePath);
            webRequest.Timeout = 1200;
            webRequest.Method = "HEAD";

            webRequest.GetResponse();
        }
        catch
        {
            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Fix your auto-redirect?  Giving an actual 404 code is useful in many other cases too (such as SEO and debugging).

Comment: To solve your immediate problem via your code sample, you could check the response headers, perhaps you're expecting a certain mime-type, and it may be different when you get the fake 404 response.

Comment: @Matthew - You nailed it!! By checking the MimeType or "ContentType" of the Response, it will return "text/html" if it hits the redirect. I have posted my fix below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Matthew Provided the correct answer. I need to check for the returned MimeType. If it comes back as a webpage(text/html; charset=utf-8), then i set the return as false. If the file does exist, the mimetype will be an image or document. See updated code below.

```
public bool verifyFile(string filePath)
    {
        bool result = true;
        string Domain = "http://www.SiteName.com/";

        try
        {
            WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(Domain + filePath);
            webRequest.Timeout = 1200;
            webRequest.Method = "HEAD";

            WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();

            result = webResponse.ContentType.ToString() == "text/html; charset=utf-8" ? false : true;
        }
        catch
        {
            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }
```